# SELECT exact table records from a comma-delimited array using T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

This I can't get my simple brain around. A comma-delimited array of products ordered is passed to a procedure like so:

```
set @array = 'productID_47, productID_4'

select productID, price from Products 
where @array like '%' + productID + '%'
```

Two records are returned. Great.
But then if I have:

```
set @array = 'productID_47'

select productID, price from Products 
where @array like '%' + productID + '%'
```

Again, two records are returned which is NOT what I want.
The product codes are fixed, sadly.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming there are no commas when there is only one item in `@array`:

```
select productID, price 
from Products  
where @array = productID --only one item, can use index
    or @array like productID + ',%'  --array starts with item, can use index
    or @array like '%, ' + productID + ',%' --item is in the middle of @array, cannot use index
    or @array like '%, ' + productID --item is at the end of @array, cannot use index
    or @array like '%,' + productID
```

Comment: +1 - Nice one. Though in the sample data it appears that the elements on `@array` have a space after a comma.

Comment: @Lamak Good point, query updated to assume (require) space after comma.